# How do I pass a Dictionary from Javascript to C# Runtime Component?

Tags: c#, collections, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have created a C# Windows Runtime Component that has a public static method that accepts an IDictionary parameter.

```
public sealed class DictionaryTest
{
    public static void print(IDictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
    }
}
```

I am accessing the library from a WinJS application and I call this method like the following in default.js:

```
var ps = new Windows.Foundation.Collections.PropertySet();
ps['testkey'] = "testvalue";
TestComponent.DictionaryTest.print(ps);
```

When I run the application I get a "No such interface supported" error. The intellisense for print() shows that it accepts a parameter of Windows.Foundation.Collections.IMap, but I cant find that collection.

How can I pass a dictionary like object from Javascript to print(IDictionary)?

EDIT:
Although @IAbstract brings up a good point, I cannot use it as a solution. My constraint is that I cannot modify the print() method. So I need to be able to pass a dictionary type object of strings from javascript to the `print(IDictionary<string, string> dict)` method.

Comment: look at the `Method Signature`..next I would ask is `ps` of type `Dictionary` or Collection` if so then you need to create the Dictionary<sting,string>` type which you are not doing based on the code that you have presented.. does `ps` have a .ToDictionary() Extension method..? if not then you could try using a `Linq` statement to create one for example you could try something like this `var dictObj = ps.ToDictionary(x => x, x=> x);` just to see if it successfully converts that collection to a `Dictionary<>`

Comment: `Windows.Foundation.Collections.PropertySet` is declared as follows:

`public sealed class PropertySet : Object,
    IPropertySet,
    IObservableMap<String, Object>,
    IDictionary<String, Object>, 
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`  

At the very least, the OP's value will need casting from `Object` to `string`.

Comment: Thanks @IAbstract, I modified print to print(IDictionary<string, object> dict) and cast the object to a string and the code works. You would think that passing a String (which is also an Object) would work :) I wonder if this is still the best way to pass a dictionary type object to a Windows Runtime Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows.Foundation.Collections.PropertySet is declared as follows:

```
public sealed class PropertySet : Object,
    IPropertySet,
    IObservableMap<String, Object>,
    IDictionary<String, Object>,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>
```

Cast the value object to string. You cannot always depend on `Object.ToString()` implicitly.